# Multilevel WPF Treeview with Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding, treeview

I just want to create a treeview using binding in wpf. I have a class (ClassRoot) as root and I have 3 properties in root class of type `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `ClassC` like the following,

```
class ClassRoot
{
    public ClassA propClassA { get; set; }
    public ClassB propClassB { get; set; }
    public ClassC propClassC { get; set; }
}
```

each class having its own properties. It may have properties of type `List` or `Enum`, etc., like below,

```
class ClassA
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   //Here ListOfValues is an enum
   public ListOfValues listValues { get; set; }

   public List<string> stringValues { get; set; }
}
```

like the above class, `ClassB` and `ClassC` also having the same structure. I want to show this in WPF treeview like the following,

- ClassRoot

  - ClassA

    - Name
    - listValues
    - stringValues
  - ClassB

    - Name
    - listValues
    - stringValues

each properties should be editable, properties of type `List` or `Enum` should be represented as `ComboBox` in treeview.
I can use hierarchical data template, but I'm confusing to implement this multi level hierarchy.
How can I proceed with this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

use [HierarchicalDataTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType    = "{x:Type src:ClassRoot}"
                              ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Divisions}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType    = "{x:Type src:ClassA}"
                              ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Teams}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType    = "{x:Type src:ClassB}"
                              ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Teams}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hello codeDom, thank you for your answer. I don't have problems in using HierarchicalDataTemplate, I can display class hierarchy in treeview, but I also wants to display properties of ClassA below to its node. I tried with template containing label for all properties of ClassA, it will display all properties as one node, I want them as separate nodes under ClassA node, also it should be editable, This is my problem...